# How to test two coefficients are simultaneously zero in GEE model in R

Tags: r, coefficients

We have a dataset in which there were 3 arms (message 1, message 2, controls) and . I am using the "geepack" package in R to construct `geeglm` models that look like this:

```
outcome = Beta1x + Beta2x + other variables #(where Beta1 = message 1 
                         #vs. controls, Beta2 = message 2 vs. controls)
```

I have p-values and 95% CI for each of the coefficients Beta1 and Beta2. Now I want to test the hypothesis that the coefficients Beta1 and Beta2 are both zero simultaneously. I was wondering if someone could explain how to do that in R. In Stata, this can be done with post-estimating testing with testparm, but I'm not sure how to do this in R.

I have not been able to figure out how to do the post-estimation testing in R.

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please?  (I think you'll need the covariance matrix associated with these parameters as well.)

Comment: As a new user at Stack Overflow, please take the tour, as well as read the info in the comment from Ben Bolker. https://stackoverflow.com/tour